# How strings are stored in Solidity on a low level?

Tags: solidity, string, bytes

So, the question is in the title, let me describe scenario:

I make raw rpc call via method `eth_call` to contract Token to a function `name` to get token name of type `string`. Below is my original response and some metrics:

```
Original response: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000557494e4753000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Length of response (with 0x prefix): 194
Formatted uncut response:               // just whitespace
Formatted cut response (only last 32 bytes): WINGS
Unused bytes (first 64 bytes): 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
```

---

It would be great to understand **what lays in those first 64 bytes** and how is it calculated.

*First I thought that it is somehow related to RLP, but I didn't find any evidence of that, so this is just my assumption.*

Thanks for help.

---

P.S.: For formatting I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745677/7310095).

Comment: I think you're looking for ABI encoding: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/abi-spec.html.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @smarx. This is really it. Looks like the first `bytes32` is just the location of the data and the second `bytes32` is the length of the data in bytes.

Comment: Yup, you got it.

Comment: Appreciate your help, @smarx. I will be glad to accept your answer if you don't mind to publish it.